# The polarization of a uniformly distributed charge on/within a sphere

Tags: electrostatics

> Suppose we confine polarization charges to be uniformly
>   distributed within a sphere of radius $R$ centred at the origin. What kind of $\mathbf{P}$ does
>   this produce? Inside and outside the dielectric?

My hunch is the following: Using the relation,

> $$ \text{div}(\mathbf{P}) = - \rho_{p},  $$

one can conclude that the magnitude of the polarization vector, assumed to be constant on a Gaussian spherical surface, decreases as $r$ increases. It abruptly becomes zero at the surface, since the vector is zero outside of polarizable matter. This indicates the presence of positive polarized (bound) charge smeared on the surface.

Am I on the right track? Please only give hints; not the answer.

Comment: Outside the sphere, you might have $\text{div}(\mathbf{P}) = 0$ if nothing else is there, but are you sure that $\mathbf{P}$ itself vanishes? I would rather think it does not, so there is no jump on the dielectric surface, hence no surface charges (at least no need to have some). Maybe the discussion needs to take into account the electric fields E and D, you may want to mention them in your question.

Comment: @claudechuber In light of the comments, I made, check problem 10 of Griffith's Electrodynamics. The questions has the functional form $P(\mathbf{r}) = k \mathbf{r}$. With that polarization, we have both volume and surface charges, where both of them are constant. Outside, we get no $E$ field. Also, I think $P$ is assumed to be zero outside of the dielectric -- that's what both Griffith's and Zangwill's book mention.